# How to make country_id/region_id/region to work in custom admin form?

Tags: magento2, adminform, country-regions

I need country/region fields in custom form in admin panel. I have following fields:

```
        <field name="country_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">somesource</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="region">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">somesource</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="region_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">somesource</item>
                <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                    <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

At the moment the problem is that select field are not populated by data. How to make the region updater to work in .xml admin forms?

Comment: I have the same problem here..

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Comment: I dont know any way to do it using ui component but it can be done using block method by this method ..
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89856/how-to-add-country-and-state-dropdown-in-admin-side-in-magento2